# Raise NSError in RubyMotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion, apiclient

I write an application which is basically just client to http API. I am trying to reuse code from [Redis Search sample](https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/tree/master/ios/RedditSearch) (`DataParser` and `JsonParser`), but when error occurs during the API call, RubyMotion is not able to raise that error. It tries to `raise` first error in error pointer, which is of `NSError` and `raise` expects `Exception` ancestor.

Is there some new way how to treat HTTP errors in RubyMotion projects?

I am not using BW::HTTP since I found it was deprecated.

Received error:

```
data_parser.rb:7:in `parse:': exception class/object expected (TypeError)
```

One of codes failing this way:

```
class DataParser
  def self.parse(url)
    error_ptr = Pointer.new(:object)
    data = NSData.alloc.initWithContentsOfURL(NSURL.URLWithString(url), options:NSDataReadingUncached, error:error_ptr)
    unless data
      NSLog error_ptr[0].inspect
      raise error_ptr[0]
    end
    data
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommended to use AFMotion: https://github.com/clayallsopp/afmotion

Comment: Thank you for recommendation. Unfortunately when I follow the guide ( https://github.com/clayallsopp/AFMotion#install ) to install AFMotion I get an error (Unable to find a specification for `AFMotion`). What do you do differently than how it is in the guide?

Comment: try: gem install afmotion or add it to your Gemfile

Comment: That's what the guide says and as I mentioned, the guide does not work for me

Comment: Now it works, so I guess some server was just down, ty